# Reset Safari 8 in Yosemite to show Welcome/Splash screen again

Tags: macos, safari, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta, safari8

Does anybody know how to reset Safari so the next time it opens it presents the welcome screen again as if it were launched for the first time in Yosemite?

Previously you just deleted its preference file but that no longer works, ive deleted all these files, and the entire Safari folder in ~/Library but it still just opens on the favourites page - is there a new hidden file or something somewhere?

So far tried deleting

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.WebKit.PluginProcess
rm -Rf ~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.LSSharedFileList.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.RSS.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/PubSub/Database
rm -Rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Safari.savedState
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset the Safari Welcome screen, open a Terminal window and enter:

```
defaults delete com.apple.Safari LastSafariVersionWithWelcomePage
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained your answer.

Comment: "Domain (com.apple.Safari) not found. Defaults have not been changed."

Comment: Back in 2015 this was the plist setting that remembered if the Welcome page has been viewed. When I try it on Mojave with Safari 14, the com.apple.Safari domain exists (i.e. there is a plist with that name in the place that the defaults command is looking for it) but that preference setting is no longer there.